# How to extend Django generic year archive view?

Tags: django, datetime, view, django-generic-views

I'm using Django's generic year archive view to display event objects by year. This may or may not be the best way to do this since I found that Django restricts the object list to the year being passed; my date range spans the current year into the next.

Here's my view:

```
class VisitingScholarsYearView(YearArchiveView):

    allow_empty = True
    allow_future = True
    date_field = 'event_date'
    template_name = "events/dvs_test.html"
    context_object_name = 'event_list'
    make_object_list = True

    def get_queryset(self):
            return Event.school_year_events.from_year(self.get_year()).filter(event_type__title='Distinguished Visiting Scholars Series')
```

Here's the manager on my model (an Event object with a DateField called event_date):

```
class SchoolYearManager(models.Manager):
    def live_events(self, start_date, end_date):
        return self.filter(status=self.model.LIVE).filter(event_date__range=(start_date, end_date))

    def this_year(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_year = now.year
        start_date = datetime.date(current_year, 7, 1)
        end_date = datetime.date((current_year + 1), 6, 30)
        return self.live_events(start_date, end_date)

def from_year(self, year):
        start_date = datetime.date(int(year), 7, 1)
        end_date = datetime.date((int(year) + 1), 6, 30)
        return self.live_events(start_date, end_date)
```

And finally, my url for the view:

```
url(r'^distinguished-visiting-scholars-series/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', VisitingScholarsYearView.as_view()),
```

When I hit the API, I get the events I expect. But the YearArchiveView appears to limit the returned events to the year I give it; this is also expected, but I'd like it to span the range I refer to in the manager (ie July 1  to June 30 ).

How can I change this behavior? Or should I attempt a different view (ListView)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use `YearArchiveView` as the base here - there's too much built-in logic around getting the objects for that date.

Instead, use `ListView` with `YearMixin`:

```
class VisitingScholarsYearView(YearMixin, ListView):
```

Comment: The YearMixin makes sense, but what am I getting from BaseDetailView? I don't have a slug or object pk to call. How would this look?

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out as well. Works great. Thanks!